# How can I not make the BINARY file when I compile the code?

Tags: c++, compilation

When I compile the code, The new BINARY file is formed. (When I compile HelloWorld.cpp file, file HelloWorld formed) and the file says that: the file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding.

Comment: Could you provide the command you run to produce the binary ?

Comment: Are you looking to build libraries instead?

Comment: It's very unclear what you mean. Creating a "BINARY file" is the entire purpose of compilation. What's what it does. Give more detail about what you're trying to do, and about what happens when you try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using gcc, compiling with the -c option will skip the linking step and will not create the binary.

Comment: The OP probably still needs the binary to run it and didn't realize the file is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The compiled file is something you want to run, but not something you want to further edit. 
To make changes, keep editing HelloWorld.cpp. To run your program, use the compiled file.

Comment: Also, when you make changes to `HelloWorld.cpp` you need to recompile in order for you changes to be reflected in the binary.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Not if `HelloWorld.cpp` is also opened and examined at runtime and logic choices made as a result of its contents ;)